Asymptotics of system of quadratic ODEs on simplex
I've asked this question on math stackexchange, however, did not get an answer. So trying my luck here instead:
Consider the system ODEs
$$
x_k' = f(x) g_k(x)\,, \quad k=1,\ldots, n
$$
on a subset of the unit simplex $\Delta = \{x \in [0,1]^n : \sum_i x_i \leq 1\}$, namely
$$
S = \{x \in \Delta : f(x) \geq 0 \}\,.
$$
Here $ f$ and $ g_k$ are linear/affine functions, so the system makes sense. Moreover, let's assume that $g_k(x)=0$, $k=1,\ldots,n$ has a unique solution $ \bar x \in S$.
I am wondering what conditions on $f$ and $g_k$ may be sufficient or necessary to guarantee that a solution satisfies
$$
x(t) \to \bar x \quad as \quad t \to \infty \ \,,
$$
provided $f(x(0)) >0$?
In other words, I want to show that possible equilibria with $f(x)=0$ are not reached in infinite time.
In fact, I have particular system in mind,
for example, take $n=3$
with
$$
f(x) := 
3x_1+2 x_2 + x_3-1\,,
$$
and
$$
g_1(x) = x_2-x_1\\
g_2(x) = x_{3}+x_{1} - 2x_2\\
g_3(x)= 1- x_1-3x_3\ \ 
 ("= x_4 + x_2-2x_3") \,.
$$
In this case $g_k( \bar x)=0$ holds for the constant vector $ \bar x = (1/4,1/4,1/4)$. Viewing $ f(x) $ as a "state-dependent speed", the system should always run into $ \bar x $, when started with an initial condition such that $ f>0$.
Numerical simulations confirm this.
I tried (unsuccessfully) asymptotic analysis of the equilibria by studying the Jacobian of the system, which became quickly messy for general functions/large $n$.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

You might consider looking at "H. L. Smith, Systems of Ordinary Di erential Equations Which Generate an Order Preserving
Flow. A Survey of Results, SIAM Review, 30 (1988), pp. 87113." Your system seems to be monotonous and under the proper conditions on f and g, irreducible. Then, a result in the above referrence is that if the equilibria set is finite, the system will converge to one of the equlibrium points (for almost all initial conditions). Also, "Monotone Dynamical Systems" by Hirsch.

The system combines a "state-dependent speed" $f(x) $, assumed to be a linear or affine function, with the dynamics encoded in $ g_k(x)$, which are also linear or affine. Because $ f(x) \geq 0 $ within $ S$, solutions remain in $ S $ for all $t$. The key is ensuring that $ f(x) > 0 $ prevents trajectories from asymptotically reaching regions where $ f(x) = 0 $.
To guarantee $ x(t) \to \bar{x} $ as $ t \to \infty $, sufficient and necessary conditions typically involve:
The divergence of the flow, $ \nabla \cdot (f(x) g_k(x)) $, should ideally be negative (or at least non-positive) to ensure that trajectories converge to a compact subset of $ S $.
The point $ \bar{x}$ must be an attractor of the dynamics. This can often be verified using the Jacobian matrix $ J(x)$ of the system, evaluated at $ \bar{x} $. Specifically, $\bar{x} $is asymptotically stable if all eigenvalues of $J(\bar{x})$ have negative real parts.
To prevent trajectories from asymptotically reaching regions where $f(x) = 0$, $ f(x) $ must decrease sufficiently rapidly as $x $ approaches the boundary of $S $ or any potential equilibria outside $ \bar{x} $.
For $n = 3 $ with the specific choices
$
   f(x) = 3x_1 + 2x_2 + x_3 - 1\,,
   $
and
$
   g_1(x) = x_2 - x_1, \quad g_2(x) = x_3 + x_1 - 2x_2, \quad g_3(x) = 1 - x_1 - 3x_3\,,
   $
the point $ \bar{x} = (1/4, 1/4, 1/4)$ satisfies $g_k(\bar{x}) = 0 $ for $k = 1, 2, 3 $.
I ran numerical simulations on Wolfram Alpha which confirm that $x(t) \to \bar{x}$ for $ f(x(0)) > 0$, suggesting that $\bar{x}$ is a global attractor for this initial condition.
Compute the Jacobian matrix $J(x)$ for the system:
$
   J(x) = \left[ f(x) \frac{\partial g_k}{\partial x_i} + g_k(x) \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} \right]_{i,k}\,.
   $
At $\bar{x}$, where $g_k(\bar{x}) = 0 $, this simplifies to
$
   J(\bar{x}) = f(\bar{x}) \frac{\partial g_k}{\partial x_i}\,.
   $
Stability can then be determined by analyzing the eigenvalues of $J(\bar{x}) $.
Construct a Lyapunov function $V(x)$ that measures the "distance" from $ x $ to $\bar{x}$. A natural candidate is
$
   V(x) = \sum_{k=1}^n g_k(x)^2\,,
   $
which satisfies $V(x) \geq 0$ with equality if and only if $ x = \bar{x} $. The time derivative along trajectories is given by
$
   \dot{V}(x) = 2 \sum_{k=1}^n g_k(x) g_k'(x) = 2f(x) \sum_{k=1}^n g_k(x)^2\,.
   $
If $f(x) > 0$, this suggests $\dot{V}(x) \leq 0$, ensuring that trajectories approach $\bar{x}$.
To ensure trajectories do not reach regions where $f(x) = 0$, analyze the level sets of $f(x)$. If $f(x) \to 0$ only at $\bar{x}$ or outside $S$, trajectories will be forced to converge to $\bar{x}$.
The asymptotic convergence to $\bar{x}$ can be guaranteed under the following conditions:

$\bar{x}$ is a stable equilibrium of the system, as verified by the eigenvalues of $J(\bar{x})$ or a Lyapunov function.

$f(x) > 0$ within $S$ and decreases sufficiently near any boundary points of $S$ to prevent escape.

The divergence of the flow is negative or sufficiently controlled to ensure dissipativity.


For your specific example, these conditions are satisfied, explaining why $x(t) \to \bar{x}$ numerically.

Can you elaborate on why stability of $ \bar{x}$ implies convergence towards it. Points satisfying $f(x)=0$ could also be stable, no?
